# Right Click Movement Not working in Unreal Engine 4.24 version c++

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I tried implementing an RTS in unreal engine c++ and currently I can select and deselect units but they won't move though I already have a function for that. Could someone take a look what I am doing wrong? Here's my code:

```
void ACoba_PlayerController::SetupInputComponent()
{
    Super::SetupInputComponent();

    InputComponent->BindAction("RightMouseClick", IE_Pressed, this, &ACoba_PlayerController::MoveReleased);
}

void ACoba_PlayerController::MoveReleased()
{
    if (SelectedActors.Num() > 0)
    {
        for (int32 i = 0; i < SelectedActors.Num(); i++)
        {
            FHitResult Hit;
            GetHitResultUnderCursor(ECC_Visibility, false, Hit);
            FVector MoveLocation = Hit.Location + FVector(i / 2 * 100, i % 2 * 100, 0);
            UAIBlueprintHelperLibrary::SimpleMoveToLocation(SelectedActors[i]->GetController(), MoveLocation);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I've already setup the input for `RightMouseClick` at the input property.
Could someone help me please. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set your **PlayerController** to receive input:

```
ACoba_PlayerController::ACoba_PlayerController()
{
    AutoReceiveInput = EAutoReceiveInput::Player0;

    /* ... */
}
```

I just tested the right button and it worked.
I'm using Unreal 4.24.2

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, and after spending a day into it, i found out the problem is not in the code itself (mine is identical than the OP), the problem was that you need to add in your map a NavMeshBoundVolume in UE editor, this will make your map floor surface "walkable" by your actors, without this the SimpleMoveToLocation function won't do anything.

I found it very annoying that there is no warning or error displayed showing that you are missing a NavMeshBoundVolume, that would save a lot of time.